# Segmentation fault(core dumped), related to perl

Tags: segmentation-fault

I upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04. After the upgrade I tried to run perl scripts, but when I use any cpan module like 
`use Data::Dumper`
etc it gives me

```
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

`perl -v` and `perl -V` gives the version and detailed explanation of what version is installed.

For example consider these 2 scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "string";
print $a,"\n";
```

This works fine

Now consider this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $a = "string";
print $a,"\n";
```

This gives `Segmentation error(core-dumped)`

I can open `man cpan` but when i type cpan on the terminal it gives me Segmentation fault error

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess, you upgraded `perl` via OS upgrade but you didn't upgrade `cpan` and its modules. And there is alway _something wrong_, hence the posts here. But _something wrong_ can't tell us what that __something__ is.

Comment: Hi alvits, When I try to run perl script with any cpan module let's say use Data::Dumper, it gives me an error of Segmentation fault

Comment: Yes you mentioned that already. Please post a [mcve] that we can run and debug to help you with. If this is not possible try [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What have we learned from the debugger output? Please post the output of the debugger as well.

Comment: I edited my question. Let me know if it is some what understandable. When you say debugger output, you mean I should run perl -d script.pl?

Comment: Your `cpan` and cpan modules are not compatible with the upgraded `perl`. First, remove `cpan` then reinstall it from the repository. From there, the error message should change and you should be able to upgrade your `cpan` modules.

Comment: Can you tell me how to proceed with the removal of cpan? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try erasing these directories: ~/.cpan ~/perl5 ~/.local/share/.cpan

That should clear out the old CPAN modules. You will need to reinstall them.